# Spatial joining syntax

Tags: postgis, sql

A standard PostGIS point-in-polygon query might look like this. ([example tutorial](http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/joins.html))

```
SELECT p.*,b.polyname
 FROM points p, shapes s
 WHERE ST_Within(p.the_geom,s.the_geom)
```

Imagine this was *not* a spatial join. Then it would look like this:

```
SELECT i.*,c.categoryname
 FROM items i, categories c
 WHERE i.zipcode = c.zipcode
```

Most SQL folks would advise rewriting that query using a variety of the `JOIN` keyword syntax:

```
SELECT i.*,c.categoryname
 FROM items i
 JOIN categories c ON i.zipcode = c.zipcode
```

**Does PostGIS offer this sort of syntax for spatial joins?** I can't find it. All I see are a lot of functions that return `true` or `false`, leading to the workaround syntax. Ideally, I would think a spatial join would look like:

```
SELECT p.*,b.polyname
 FROM points p
 JOIN shapes s
 ON 
 p.the_geom IS WITHIN s.the_geom
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use `[FULL|INNER|LEFT|RIGHT|OUTER|CROSS] JOIN` syntax [supported by PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html), the query would still need [`ST_Within()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html). I've never seen any spatial database use `IS WITHIN`, since there could be parameters for the spatial relation, such as [`ST_DWithin`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). It should look like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM points p
INNER JOIN shapes s ON ST_Within(p.the_geom, s.the_geom)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I think I see where I went wrong. `i.zip = c.zip` would also evaluate to true or false, so really the `JOIN ... ON` syntax can accept any function or comparison that returns true or false.

And PostgreSQL would need a serious change to its query parser to be able to accept new comparison operators like `WITHIN`, but all that work might not even make sense. So spatial functions it is.

Comment: The `b.polyname` in this example should be `p.polyname`
Can't edit the answer because < 6 character edits are not allowed. :(

Comment: @MartinBurch similar to your question, you can just use `p.*` to show all of the fields from the joined `points`